# How can I safely use WebKitGTK from a forked thread?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, gtk, webkitgtk

I'm trying to make a simple app in Haskell using GTK3 and WebKit. This code creates and shows a window containing a `WebView` inside, which displays a random number each time a key gets pressed.

```
import           Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import           Control.Concurrent (forkOS)
import           System.Random (randomIO)
import           Graphics.UI.Gtk                   -- gtk3
import           Graphics.UI.Gtk.WebKit.WebView    -- webkitgtk3


main = forkOS $ do

  -- Init GTK.
  initGUI

  -- Create a window which would finish the GTK loop
  -- after being closed.
  window <- windowNew
  window `after` objectDestroy $
    mainQuit

  -- Create a WebView inside.
  webView <- webViewNew
  set window [containerChild := webView]

  -- Make the WebView display a random number on key press.
  webView `on` keyReleaseEvent $ lift $ do
    x <- randomIO :: IO Int
    webViewLoadString webView (show x) Nothing Nothing ""
    return True

  -- Run GTK.
  widgetShowAll window
  mainGUI
```

When I run it in GHCi (7.8.3), it works fine. However, when I run it again without quitting GHCi, the `WebView` never shows anything – just plain white area. This is upsetting, as I like to tinker with code in GHCi.

Of course, everything works just fine if I don't use `forkOS` and run the whole thing in the main thread. What's the reason for this limitation (I thought all GTK functions considered the “main” thread to be the one in which `initGUI` was called), and can it be overcome somehow?

Comment: You may need to explicitly run in the bound thread with `Control.Concurrent.runInBoundThread`.

Comment: @vivian: could you expand on that? I thought about this, but adding `runInBoundThread` right before or after `forkOS` didn't help, and adding `print =<< isCurrentThreadBound` showed that the thread was already bounded.

Comment: Does it work as expected outside of GHCi?  Probably some event loop is getting stopped and not restarted when you run it twice within a single process.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. outside of GHCi it doesn't even show the window the 2nd time, just exits immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If it works like python(I don't know haskell) you should keep the `gtk main loop` in the `main thread`.

In your second thread call [g_idle_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add) with a callback to make changes with gtk, and `transport data between` your `second thread`, and `gtk`. You should start your non-main thread before `gtk main` so it's not blocked.

I'm sure there is a binding of `g_idle_add` in haskell. There is also g_timeout_add which works for this too.

This all has something to do with gtk not being thread safe.